# accessing control/Checkbox in editform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a problem with accessing the `Checkbox` in my editForm-Template, that is nested in a Grid.

```
 <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template" EditColumn-UniqueName="insertForm">
                            <FormTemplate>  
                                <table>


                                    <tr>                                           
                                    <td>Add : </td>
                                    <td>
                                          <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="addCB" />

                                    </td>                                                                      
                                </tr>                                    
                                <tr>

                            </table> 
                        </FormTemplate>
                    </EditFormSettings>
```

The EditFormTemplate is like i said, nested in a Grid. I just didn`t post it here, to make it more clearly.

my problem is now that I neither can access the checkbox via javascript like :

```
function isAddSwitched() {

         var checkbox = $find("<%= addCB.ClientID%>");
            alert(checkbox.get_checked());
        }
```

nor can i access it through code behind like this :

```
If addCB.Checked Then
                    'code here
                End If
```

When I move the Checkbox out of the Template field its no problem at all. But INSIDE it, it seems impossible to access it.

It would be greatif someone could help me with that problem !!

Kind Regards,

Malte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when controls are placed in a grid, they are not declared in the designer file as page controls.

You will have to get hold of them differently depending on what event is happening:

1. Control postback i.e. OnCheckedChanged: the sender object will be your checkbox
2. Row event e.g. OnItemDataBound, OnRowInsert, etc: you can get hold of the checkbox by using e.Item.FindControl("addCB");

Comment: Thank you very, very much ! I'm new to ASP.NET (and the Telerik Framework) and you just helped me alot !

Comment: I hope i don't bother you, but can you tell me how i can access a TextBox in that TemplateField ? There is no similar function for items like Checkboxes, like the "FindControl" function.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on telerik website: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html